# Customize Sonatype Nexus appearance (header or menu)

Tags: java, maven, nexus, sonatype

I've been asked to customize the [Sonatype Nexus OSS](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-oss) web interface.  I know [the logo](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/nexus-branding.html) is easy to change, but I do believe that adding hyperlinks to the header or menu would require changes to the source code and rebuilding the whole java project with maven.

Am I correct? Or is there a way to modify any files after the archive is extracted on the host machine so as to change the header or menu on the website?

If I'm correct, where in the source code can I add a hyperlink to the header?

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely have a look at http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/plugdev.html where the plugin development of Nexus OSS is introduced and links to example code is given. Depending on the impact of your needs, it may be sufficient to create an easy header plugin and provide the link to your nexus instance.

This should be the preferable way, since updating the Nexus would result in reworking your operative changes (say, you change any code directly). A plugin will be more stable to these changes.

hth,
fred